# Display the function body in Bash

Tags: bash, function

I have setup several functions in my `.bashrc` file. I would like to just display the actual code of the function and not execute it, to quickly refer to something.

Is there any way, we could see the function definition?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `declare` builtin's `-f` option does that:

```
bash-4.2$ declare -f apropos1
apropos1 () 
{ 
    apropos "$@" | grep ' (1.*) '
}
```

I use `type` for that purpose, it is shorter to type ;)

```
bash-4.2$ type apropos1
apropos1 is a function
apropos1 () 
{ 
    apropos "$@" | grep ' (1.*) '
}
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, `type`  outputs: `<function> is a shell function from <location>`, and not the content.

Comment: @Timo, are you sure that is Bash? Sounds like Zsh behavior.

Comment: thanks for the hint, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478673/how-to-show-zsh-function-definition-like-bash-type-myfunc) is the solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `type` command to do this.

`type yourfunc` will print the function to STDOUT. As [`man type`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/type) says,

> The type utility shall indicate how each argument would be interpreted if used as a command name.

Comment: `man type`? Shell builtins usually have no man page on my system.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link. The system I use is Arch Linux.

Comment: Thank you. Seems the [_man-pages_](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/man-pages/) package contains much more on Arch.

Comment: No problem: as it is one of the POSIX man pages, I thought it would be widely distributed...

Comment: `help type` shows the Bash-specific information.

Answer (score 0):

for builtin commands' info use:

```
help [-s|-d] COMMAND1 COMMAND2 ....
```

for example:

```
help help alias
```

For info about all of them type, for example:

```
help -s ''
```

Answer (score -1):

`type` works if you declared your function in the shell but `which` works even if you sourced the function from another file.

Comment: That's not true. `type` works fine no matter where you've sourced the function from. Try `printf 'foo(){ echo "hi"; }\n' > file; . file; type foo`. Actually, `which` doesn't work with functions at all, it only finds commands in your PATH. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Comment: @terdon, depends on the implementation of `which`, GNU `which` can be configured to dump function definitions (as you'll see at the Q&A you're linking to)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas even there, you would need something like `declare -f | which --read-functions --tty-only $functionName` and it still makes no difference whether the function was defined in the current shell or sourced from a file.