# Why not use "which"? What to use then?

Tags: shell, history, which, portability

When looking for the path to an executable or checking what would happen if you enter a command name in a Unix shell, there's a plethora of different utilities (`which`, `type`, `command`, `whence`, `where`, `whereis`, `whatis`, `hash`, etc).

We often hear that `which` should be avoided. Why? What should we use instead?

Comment: I think most arguments against using `which` are assuming an interactive shell context. This question is tagged /portability. So i interpret the question in this context as "what to use instead of `which` to find the first executable of a given name in the `$PATH`". Most answers and reasons against `which` deal with aliases, builtins and functions, which in most real-world portable shell scripts are just of academic interest. Locally defined aliases aren't inherited when running a shell script (unless you source it with `.`).

Comment: @MattBianco, yes, `csh` (and `which` is still a `csh` script on most commercial Unices) does read `~/.cshrc` when non-interactive. That's why you'll notice csh scripts usually start with `#! /bin/csh -f`. `which` does not because it _aims_ to give you the aliases, because it's meant as a tool for (interactive) users of `csh`. POSIX shells users have `command -v`.

Comment: @rudimeier, then the answer would be _always unless your shell is `(t)csh` (or you don't mind if it doesn't give you the correct result), use `type` or `command -v` instead_. See the answers for _why_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How would I rewrite `stat $(which ls)` using `type` or `command -v`? I'm usually just interested in "looking for a path to an executable". `which` seems to be exactly the right tool for this. I see what your question and answer is pointing to, but this is not about *all* use cases of `which`.

Comment: @rudimeier, (`stat $(which ls)` is wrong for several reasons (missing `--`, missing quotes), not only the usage of `which`). You'd use `stat -- "$(command -v ls)"`. That assumes `ls` is indeed a command found on the file system (not a builtin of your shell, or function of alias). `which` might give you the wrong path (not the path that your shell would execute if you entered `ls`) or give you an alias as defined in the configuration of some other shells...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Don't you get my point? I am NOT interested about builtin, function or aliases. I WANT the **path to the executable file name**. The fact that `ls` *is* a function on my system is the best reason why to use `which` in this case. Instead of `stat` my real usage is often this one ```rpm -q --whatprovides $(which ls)```.  And yes, I don't use quotes interactively when I know that I don't need any. My PATH never contains whitespaces otherwise I consider it a bug in my setup and accept undefined behavior.

Comment: @rudimeier, again, there are a number of conditions under which many `which` implementations would not give you even the `ls` that would be found by a look-up of `$PATH` (regardless of what `ls` may invoke in your shell). `sh -c 'command -v ls'`, or `zsh -c 'rpm -q --whatprovides =ls'` are more likely to give you the correct answer. The point here is that `which` is a broken heritage from `csh`.

Comment: I just use `whence -p` on mksh, but there’s no equivalent for `which -a`, so `alias which='whence -p'` will fail (or force you to use `\which -a`)… but the POSIX sh `command` command is probably your best bet.

Comment: @mirabilos, most `which` implementations including the original csh script (as found on  most commercial/traditional Unices) or the `tcsh` builtin don't have a `-a` option. In `zsh`, the equivalent of `which -a` would be `whence -ca`, not `whence -pa` which only reports the paths of _executables_.

Comment: Highly ranked Q&A at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 541):

Here is all you never thought you would ever not want to know about it:

### Summary

To get the pathname of an executable in a Bourne-like shell script (there are a few caveats; see below):

```
ls=$(command -v ls)
```

To find out if a given command exists:

```
if command -v given-command > /dev/null; then
  echo given-command is available
else
  echo given-command is not available
fi
```

At the prompt of an interactive Bourne-like shell:

```
type ls
```

The `which` command is a broken heritage from the C-Shell and is better left alone in Bourne-like shells.

### Use Cases

There's a distinction between looking for that information as part of a script or interactively at the shell prompt.

At the shell prompt, the typical use case is: *this command behaves weirdly, am I using the right one? What exactly happened when I typed `mycmd`? Can I look further at what it is?*

In that case, you want to know what your shell does when you invoke the command without actually invoking the command.

In shell scripts, it tends to be quite different. In a shell script there's no reason why you'd want to know where or what a command is if all you want to do is run it. Generally, what you want to know is the path of the executable, so you can get more information out of it (like the path to another file relative to that, or read information from the content of the executable file at that path).

Interactively, you may want to know about *all* the `my-cmd` commands available on the system, in scripts, rarely so.

Most of the available tools (as is often the case) have been designed to be used interactively.

### History

A bit of history first.

The early Unix shells until the late 70s had no functions or aliases. Only the traditional looking up of executables in `$PATH`. `csh` introduced aliases around 1978 (though `csh` was first *released* in `2BSD`, in May 1979), and also the processing of a `.cshrc` for users to customize the shell (every shell, as `csh`, reads `.cshrc` even when not interactive like in scripts).

While the Bourne shell was first released in Unix V7 earlier in 1979, function support was only added much later (1984 in SVR2), and anyway, it never had some `rc` file (the `.profile` is to configure your environment, not the shell *per se*).

`csh` got a lot more popular than the Bourne shell as (though it had an awfully worse syntax than the Bourne shell) it was adding a lot of more convenient and nice features for interactive use.

In `3BSD` (1980), a [`which` csh script](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-3/usr/ucb/which) was added for the `csh` users to help identify an executable, and it's a hardly different script you can find as `which` on many commercial Unices nowadays (like Solaris, HP/UX, AIX or Tru64).

That script reads the user's `~/.cshrc` (like all `csh` scripts do unless invoked with `csh -f`), and looks up the provided command name(s) in the list of aliases and in `$path` (the array that `csh` maintains based on `$PATH`).

Here you go: `which` came first for the most popular shell at the time (and `csh` was still popular until the mid-90s), which is the main reason why it got documented in books and is still widely used.

Note that, even for a `csh` user, that `which` csh script does not necessarily give you the right information. It gets the aliases defined in `~/.cshrc`, not the ones you may have defined later at the prompt or for instance by `source`ing another `csh` file, and (though that would not be a good idea), `PATH` might be redefined in `~/.cshrc`.

Running that `which` command from a Bourne shell would still lookup aliases defined in your `~/.cshrc`, but if you don't have one because you don't use `csh`, that would still probably get you the right answer.

A similar functionality was not added to the Bourne shell until 1984 in SVR2 with the `type` builtin command. The fact that it is builtin (as opposed to an external script) means that it *can* give you the right information (to some extent) as it has access to the internals of the shell.

The initial `type` command suffered from a similar issue as the `which` script in that it didn't return a failure exit status if the command was not found. Also, for executables, contrary to `which`, it output something like `ls is /bin/ls` instead of just `/bin/ls` which made it less easy to use in scripts.

Unix Version 8's (not released in the wild) Bourne shell had its `type` builtin renamed to `whatis` and extended to also report about parameters and print function definitions. It also fixed `type` issue of not returning failure when failing to find a name.

`rc`, the shell of Plan9 (the once-to-be successor of Unix) (and its derivatives like `akanga` and `es`) have `whatis` as well.

The Korn shell (a subset of which the POSIX `sh` definition is based on), developed in the mid-80s but not widely available before 1988, added many of the `csh` features (line editor, aliases...) on top of the Bourne shell. It added its own `whence` builtin (in addition to `type`) which took several options (`-v` to provide with the `type`-like verbose output, and `-p` to look only for executables (not aliases/functions...)).

Coincidental to the turmoil with regards to the copyright issues between AT&T and Berkeley, a few *free software* shell implementations came out in the late 80s early 90s. All of the Almquist shell (`ash`, to be replacement of the Bourne shell in BSDs), the public domain implementation of `ksh` (`pdksh`), `bash` (sponsored by the FSF), `zsh` came out in-between 1989 and 1991.

Ash, though meant to be a replacement for the Bourne shell, didn't have a `type` builtin until much later (in NetBSD 1.3 and FreeBSD 2.3), though it had `hash -v`. OSF/1 `/bin/sh` had a `type` builtin which always returned 0 up to OSF/1 v3.x. `bash` didn't add a `whence` but added a `-p` option to `type` to print the path (`type -p` would be like `whence -p`) and `-a` to report *all* the matching commands. `tcsh` made `which` builtin and added a `where` command acting like `bash`'s `type -a`. `zsh` has them all.

The `fish` shell (2005) has a `type` command implemented as a function.

The `which` csh script meanwhile was removed from NetBSD (as it was builtin in tcsh and of not much use in other shells), and the functionality added to `whereis` (when invoked as `which`, `whereis` behaves like `which` except that it only looks up executables in `$PATH`). In OpenBSD and FreeBSD, `which` was also changed to one written in C that looks up commands in `$PATH` only.

### Implementations

There are dozens of implementations of a `which` command on various Unices with different syntax and behaviour.

On Linux (beside the builtin ones in `tcsh` and `zsh`) we find several implementations. On recent Debian systems for instance, it's a simple POSIX shell script that looks for commands in `$PATH`.

`busybox` also has a `which` command.

There is a `GNU` `which` which is probably the most extravagant one. It tries to extend what the `which` csh script did to other shells: you can tell it what your aliases and functions are so that it can give you a better answer (and I believe some Linux distributions set some global aliases around that for `bash` to do that).

`zsh` has a couple of *operators* to expand to the path of executables: the `=` *filename expansion* operator and the `:c` history expansion modifier (here applied to *parameter expansion*):

```
$ print -r -- =ls
/bin/ls
$ cmd=ls; print -r -- $cmd:c
/bin/ls
```

`zsh`, in the `zsh/parameters` module also makes the command hash table as the `commands` associative array:

```
$ print -r -- $commands[ls]
/bin/ls
```

The `whatis` utility (except for the one in Unix V8 Bourne shell or Plan 9 `rc`/`es`) is not really related as it's for documentation only (greps the whatis database, that is the man page synopsis').

`whereis` was also added in `3BSD` at the same time as `which` though it was written in `C`, not `csh` and is used to lookup at the same time, the executable, man page and source but not based on the current environment. So again, that answers a different need.

Now, on the standard front, POSIX specifies the `command -v` and `-V` commands (which used to be optional until POSIX.2008). UNIX specifies the `type` command (no option). That's all (`where`, `which`, `whence` are not specified in any standard).

Up to some version, `type` and `command -v` were optional in the Linux Standard Base specification which explains why for instance some old versions of `posh` (though based on `pdksh` which had both) didn't have either. `command -v` was also added to some Bourne shell implementations (like on Solaris).

### Status Today

The status nowadays is that `type` and `command -v` are ubiquitous in all the Bourne-like shells (though, as noted by @jarno, note the caveat/bug in `bash` when not in POSIX mode or some descendants of the Almquist shell below in comments). `tcsh` is the only shell where you would want to use `which` (as there's no `type` there and `which` is builtin).

In the shells other than `tcsh` and `zsh`, `which` may tell you the path of the given executable as long as there's no alias or function by that same name in any of our `~/.cshrc`, `~/.bashrc` or any shell startup file and you don't define `$PATH` in your `~/.cshrc`. If you have an alias or function defined for it, it may or may not tell you about it, or tell you the wrong thing.

If you want to know about all the commands by a given name, there's nothing portable. You'd use `where` in `tcsh` or `zsh`, `type -a` in `bash` or `zsh`, `whence -a` in ksh93 and in other shells, you can use `type` in combination with `which -a` which may work.

### Recommendations

#### Getting the pathname to an executable

Now, to get the pathname of an executable in a script, there are a few caveats:

```
ls=$(command -v ls)
```

would be the standard way to do it.

There are a few issues though:

- It is not possible to know the path of the executable without executing it. All the `type`, `which`, `command -v`... all use heuristics to find out the path. They loop through the `$PATH` components and find the first non-directory file for which you have execute permission. However, depending on the shell, when it comes to executing the command, many of them (Bourne, AT&T ksh, zsh, ash...) will just execute them in the order of `$PATH` until the `execve` system call doesn't return with an error. For instance if `$PATH` contains `/foo:/bar` and you want to execute `ls`, they will first try to execute `/foo/ls` or if that fails `/bar/ls`. Now execution of `/foo/ls` may fail because you don't have execution permission but also for many other reasons, like it's not a valid executable. `command -v ls` would report `/foo/ls` if you have execution permission for `/foo/ls`, but running `ls` might actually run `/bar/ls` if `/foo/ls` is not a valid executable.
- if `foo` is a builtin or function or alias, `command -v foo` returns `foo`. With some shells like `ash`, `pdksh` or `zsh`, it may also return `foo` if `$PATH` includes the empty string and there's an executable `foo` file in the current directory. There are some circumstances where you may need to take that into account. Keep in mind for instance that the list of builtins varies with the shell implementation (for instance, `mount` is sometimes builtin for busybox `sh`), and for instance `bash` can get functions from the environment.
- if `$PATH` contains relative path components (typically `.` or the empty string which both refer to the current directory but could be anything), depending on the shell, `command -v cmd` might not output an absolute path. So the path you obtain at the time you run `command -v` will no longer be valid after you `cd` somewhere else.
- Anecdotal: with the ksh93 shell, if `/opt/ast/bin` (though that exact path can vary on different systems I believe) is in your `$PATH`, ksh93 will make available a few extra builtins (`chmod`, `cmp`, `cat`...), but `command -v chmod` will return `/opt/ast/bin/chmod` even if that path doesn't exist.

#### Determining whether a command exists

To find out if a given command exists standardly, you can do:

```
if command -v given-command > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo given-command is available
else
  echo given-command is not available
fi
```

### Where one might want to use `which`

#### `(t)csh`

In `csh` and `tcsh`, you don't have much choice. In `tcsh`, that's fine as `which` is builtin. In `csh`, that will be the system `which` command, which may not do what you want in a few cases.

#### Find commands only in some shells

A case where it might make sense to use `which` is if you want to know the path of a command, ignoring potential shell builtins or functions in `bash`, `csh` (not `tcsh`), `dash`, or `Bourne` shell scripts, that is shells that don't have `whence -p` (like `ksh` or `zsh`), `command -ev` (like `yash`), `whatis -p` (`rc`, `akanga`) or a builtin `which` (like `tcsh` or `zsh`) on systems where `which` is available and is not the `csh` script.

If those conditions are met, then:

```
echo=$(which echo)
```

would give you the path of the first `echo` in `$PATH` (except in corner cases), regardless of whether `echo` also happens to be a shell builtin/alias/function or not.

In other shells, you'd prefer:

- **zsh**: `echo==echo` or `echo=$commands[echo]` or `echo=${${:-echo}:c}`
- **ksh**, **zsh**: `echo=$(whence -p echo)`
- **yash**: `echo=$(command -ev echo)`
- **rc**, **akanga**: `` echo=`whatis -p echo` `` (beware of paths with spaces)
- **fish**: `set echo (type -fp echo)`

Note that if all you want to do is *run* that `echo` command, you don't have to get its path, you can just do:

```
env echo this is not echoed by the builtin echo
```

For instance, with `tcsh`, to prevent the builtin `which` from being used:

```
set Echo = "`env which echo`"
```

#### When you do need an external command

Another case where you may want to use `which` is when you actually *need* an external command. POSIX requires that all shell builtins (like `command`) be also available as external commands, but unfortunately, that's not the case for `command` on many systems. For instance, it's rare to find a `command` command on Linux based operating systems while most of them have a `which` command (though different ones with different options and behaviours).

Cases where you may want an external command would be wherever you would execute a command without invoking a POSIX shell.

The `system("some command line")`, `popen()`... functions of C or various languages do invoke a shell to parse that command line, so `system("command -v my-cmd")` do work in them. An exception to that would be `perl` which optimises out the shell if it doesn't see any shell special character (other than space). That also applies to its backtick operator:

```
$ perl -le 'print system "command -v emacs"'
-1
$ perl -le 'print system ":;command -v emacs"'
/usr/bin/emacs
0

$ perl -e 'print `command -v emacs`'
$ perl -e 'print `:;command -v emacs`'
/usr/bin/emacs
```

The addition of that `:;` above forces `perl` to invoke a shell there. By using `which`, you wouldn't have to use that trick.

Comment: @Joe, `which` is a `csh` script on many commercial Unices. The reason is historical, that's why I gave the history, so people understand where it came from, why people got used to using it and why actually there's no reason you should be using it. And yes, some people use (t)csh. Not everybody uses Linux yet

Comment: I suppose I won't be using `which` anymore. Served me well for a very long time. Never ever used anything but bourne shells through ...

Comment: @Joe FreeBSD uses csh for system scripts.

Comment: @jordanm TL;DR: `type which`?

Comment: After reading this post, I have found a lot of context for the answer, but not the answer itself. Where in this post does it actually say why *not* to use `which`, as opposed to things you might be trying to use `which` to do, the history of `which`, implementations of `which`, other commands to do related tasks, or reasons to actually use `which`? Why are the other commands *better*? What do they do differently from `which`? How do they avoid its pitfalls? This answer actually spends more words on the problems with the alternatives than the problems with `which`.

Comment: In fish shell, `type -fp` directly points to `which`. The only difference is that it shows an error message on <del>STDERR</del> STDOUT if the file doesn't exist. There are no advantages for using `type -fp` over `which`, and generally `which` is more readable.

Comment: `command`'s return is spec'd like: ***126** The utility specified by **command_name** was found but could not be invoked. **127** An error occurred in the `command` utility or the utility specified by **command_name** could not be found. Otherwise, the exit status of `command` shall be that of the simple command specified by the arguments to `command`.*... and so, in a lot of cases, it could be more useful just to run `command` *command* straight off and test `$?` after rather than looking for it first with `command -v`. You can limit its path search w/ `command -p` as well.

Comment: This rant may have some basis (debian has a which /bin/sh script). OS X (which is BSD) has an exe and the man states "The which utility was originally written in Perl and was contributed by Wolfram Schneider <wosch@FreeBSD.org>. The current version of which was rewritten in C by Daniel Papasian <dpapasia@andrew.cmu.edu>. June 21, 2002 BSD"

Comment: `command` is described by POSIX.

Comment: In contrary to what the answer claims, `command -v` does not check for execute permission, at least if you do call it by pure file name argument without path. I tested by dash 0.5.8 and GNU bash 4.3.48.

Comment: @jarno, I can't reproduce. Possibly you've tested by removing the execute permission to an executable that had been hashed while it had execute permission (in which case the shell would try to execute it by that path so `command -v` would be right to report that path).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If I create new file by `touch /usr/bin/mytestfile` and thereafter run `command -v mytestfile`, it will give the path (whereas `which mytestfile`does not).

Comment: @jarno, oh yes, you're right. `bash` will settle on a non-executable file if it can't find an executable one, so it's "OK" (though in practice one would rather `command -v`/`type` return an error) as that's the command it would try to execute when you run `mytestfile`, but the `dash` behaviour is buggy, as if there's a non-executable `cmd` ahead of an executable one, `command -v` returns the non-executable one while executing `cmd` would execute the executable one (the wrong one is also hashed). FreeBSD `sh` (also based on `ash`) has the same bug. zsh, yash, ksh, mksh, bash as sh are OK.

Comment: This is a very thorough exposé. However, what is meant by using `ls=$(command -v ls)? Doesn’t it assign the output to a variable `$ls`?

Comment: **No** `command -v which` doesn't provide the *full path to which` in zsh for example. That is not a portable solution. **No** `command -v given-command` doesn't tell if an external executable exists, it also include builtins. Try `zsh -c 'command -v exit; echo $?'` There is no external command `exit`, it makes no sense. As an executable for `cd` also makes no sense. But the shell answer with `success` (0).

Comment: `command -v ls` prints `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`. But I need the path to `ls` executable. So `which` is still better for getting path to executable.

Comment: @user2357112  Agree. I downvoted. So many history and useless info.

Comment: This is a truly magnificent ["chronicle"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chronicle?adobe_mc=MCORGID%3DAA9D3B6A630E2C2A0A495C40%2540AdobeOrg%7CTS%3D1709421240) on the `which` command. Now - if we only had one for `whereis`, I'd be most happy  :)

Answer (score 69):

The reasons why one may not want to use `which` have already been explained, but here are a few examples on a few systems where `which` actually fails.

On Bourne-like shells, we're comparing the output of `which` with the output of `type` (`type` being a shell builtin, it's meant to be the ground truth, as it's the shell telling us how it would invoke a command).

Many cases are *corner* cases, but bear in mind that `which`/`type` are often used in corner cases (to find the answer to an unexpected behaviour like: *why on earth is that command behaving like that, which one am I calling?*).

### Most systems, most Bourne-like shells: functions

The most obvious case is for functions:

```
$ type ls
ls is a function
ls ()
{
[ -t 1 ] && set -- -F "$@";
command ls "$@"
}
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

The reason being that `which` only reports about executables, and sometimes about aliases (though not always the ones of *your* shell), not functions.

The GNU which man page has a broken (as they forgot to quote `$@`) example on how to use it to report functions as well, but just like for aliases, because it doesn't implement a shell syntax parser, it's easily fooled:

```
$ which() { (alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot "$@";}
$ f() { echo $'\n}\ng ()\n{ echo bar;\n}\n' >> ~/foo; }
$ type f
f is a function
f ()
{
echo '
}
g ()
{ echo bar;
}
' >> ~/foo
}
$ type g
bash: type: g: not found
$ which f
f ()
{
echo '
}
$ which g
g ()
{ echo bar;
}
```

### Most systems, most Bourne-like shells: builtins

Another obvious case is builtins or keywords, as `which` being an external command has no way to know which builtins your shell have (and some shells like `zsh`, `bash` or `ksh` can load builtins dynamically):

```
$ type echo . time
echo is a shell builtin
. is a shell builtin
time is a shell keyword
$ which echo . time
/bin/echo
which: no . in (/bin:/usr/bin)
/usr/bin/time
```

(that doesn't apply to `zsh` where `which` is builtin)

### Solaris 10, AIX 7.1, HP/UX 11i, Tru64 5.1 and many others:

```
$ csh
% which ls
ls:   aliased to ls -F
% unalias ls
% which ls
ls:   aliased to ls -F
% ksh
$ which ls
ls:   aliased to ls -F
$ type ls
ls is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/ls
```

That is because on most commercial Unices, `which` (like in the original implementation on 3BSD) is a `csh` script that reads `~/.cshrc`.
The aliases it will report are the ones defined there regardless of the aliases you currently have defined and regardless of the shell you're actually using.

In HP/UX or Tru64:

```
% echo 'setenv PATH /bin:/usr/bin' >> ~/.cshrc
% setenv PATH ~/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
% ln -s /bin/ls ~/bin/
% which ls
/bin/ls
```

(the Solaris and AIX versions have fixed that issue by saving `$path` before reading the `~/.cshrc` and restoring it before looking up the command(s))

```
$ type 'a b'
a b is /home/stephane/bin/a b
$ which 'a b'
no a in /usr/sbin /usr/bin
no b in /usr/sbin /usr/bin
```

Or:

```
$ d="$HOME/my bin"
$ mkdir "$d"; PATH=$PATH:$d
$ ln -s /bin/ls "$d/myls"
$ type myls
myls is /home/stephane/my bin/myls
$ which myls
no myls in /usr/sbin /usr/bin /home/stephane/my bin
```

(of course, being a `csh` script you can't expect it to work with arguments containing spaces...)

### CentOS 6.4, bash

```
$ type which
which is aliased to `alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
$ alias foo=': "|test|"'
$ which foo
alias foo=': "|test|"'
        /usr/bin/test
$ alias $'foo=\nalias bar='
$ unalias bar
-bash: unalias: bar: not found
$ which bar
alias bar='
```

On that system, there's an alias defined system-wide that wraps the GNU `which` command.

The bogus output is because `which` reads the output of `bash`'s `alias` but doesn't know how to parse it properly and uses heuristics (one alias per line, looks for the first found command after a `|`, `;`, `&`...)

The worst thing on CentOS is that `zsh` has a perfectly fine `which` builtin command but CentOS managed to break it by replacing it with a non-working alias to GNU `which`.

### Debian 7.0, ksh93:

(though applies to most systems with many shells)

```
$ unset PATH
$ which which
/usr/local/bin/which
$ type which
which is a tracked alias for /bin/which
```

On Debian, `/bin/which` is a `/bin/sh` script. In my case, `sh` being `dash` but it's the same when it's `bash`.

An unset `PATH` is not to disable `PATH` lookup, but means using the system's *default PATH* which unfortunately on Debian, nobody agrees on (`dash` and `bash` have `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, `zsh` has `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/local/bin`, `ksh93` has `/bin:/usr/bin`, `mksh` has `/usr/bin:/bin` (`$(getconf PATH)`), `execvp()` (like in `env`) has `:/bin:/usr/bin` (yes, looks in the current directory first!)).

Which is why `which` gets it wrong above since it's using `dash`'s default `PATH` which is different from `ksh93`'s

It's not better with GNU `which` which reports:

```
which: no which in ((null))
```

(interestingly, there is indeed a `/usr/local/bin/which` on my system which is actually an `akanga` script that came with `akanga` (an `rc` shell derivative where the default `PATH` is `/usr/ucb:/usr/bin:/bin:.`))

### bash, any system:

The one [Chris is referring to in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85280/22565):

```
$ PATH=$HOME/bin:/bin
$ ls /dev/null
/dev/null
$ cp /bin/ls bin
$ type ls
ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
$ command -v ls
/bin/ls
$ which ls
/home/chazelas/bin/ls
```

Also after calling `hash` manually:

```
$ type -a which
which is /usr/local/bin/which
which is /usr/bin/which
which is /bin/which
$ hash -p /bin/which which
$ which which
/usr/local/bin/which
$ type which
which is hashed (/bin/which)
```

### Now a case where `which` and sometimes `type` fail:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ echo '#!/bin/echo' > a/foo
$ echo '#!/' > b/foo
$ chmod +x a/foo b/foo
$ PATH=b:a:$PATH
$ which foo
b/foo
$ type foo
foo is b/foo
```

Now, with some shells:

```
$ foo
bash: ./b/foo: /: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

With others:

```
$ foo
a/foo
```

Neither `which` nor `type` can know in advance that `b/foo` cannot be executed. Some shells like `bash`, `ksh` or `yash`, when invoking `foo` will indeed try to run `b/foo` and report an error, while others (like `zsh`, `ash`, `csh`, `Bourne`, `tcsh`) will run `a/foo` upon the failure of the `execve()` system call on `b/foo`.

Comment: `mksh` actually uses something different for the default `$PATH`: first, the operating system’s compile-time constant `_PATH_DEFPATH` is used (most commonly on the BSDs), then, `confstr(_CS_PATH, …)` is used (POSIX), and if both don’t exist or fail, `/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin` is used.

Comment: In your 1st example, even if `ls` is a function it is using `ls` from PATH. And `which` is fine to tell you which one is used `/usr/bin/ls`  or `/usr/local/bin/ls`. I don't see "Why not use which"....

Comment: @rudimeier, That `which ls` will give me `/bin/ls` regardless of whether the `ls` function calls `/bin/ls` or `/opt/gnu/bin/ls` or `dir` or nothing at all. IOW, `which` (that which implementations, IMMV) is giving something irrelevant

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. No, no, no. I *know* already that my `ls` is a function. I *know* that my `ls` function is calling `ls` from `PATH`. Now `which` tells me where the file is. You only see one single use case: "What would my shell do with this command." For this use case `which` is wrong, correct. But there are other use cases where (GNU) `which` is exactly the right thing.

Comment: @rudimeter, depends on the `which` implementation. Some will tell you it's an alias (if you have an alias configured, or if there is a `~/.cshrc` in your home that has such an alias), some will give you a path but the wrong one under some conditions. `sh -c 'command -v ls'`, though not perfect is still more likely to give you the right answer to that different requirement (and is also standard).

Comment: Which doesn't fail. It only fails to work as you want it to. IMO (and also the Debian which executable) it should only provide full paths to executables on the PATH. What which doesn't do and shouldn't do is to interpret the internals of the shells. That is sure to fail.

Comment: *dash's default PATH is different from ksh93's* only if you override the default one.

Comment: Note that CentOS doesn't break things, insomuch as that project doesn't make decisions on the packaging in the base OS. It's either from Fedora or something reconfigured in RHEL. Actually, though, I suspect that this is some weird thing held over from early Red Hat Linux in the 90s.

Answer (score 27):

One thing which (from my quick skim) it seems that Stephane didn't mention is that `which` has no idea about your shell's path hash table. This has the effect that it might return a result which is not representative of what actually is run, which makes it ineffective in debugging.

Comment: Which means - after trying out the code which Stéphane added in response to Chris' answer - that the shell remembers (hashes) where it found something, and if you later add another version of the same command at a place earlier in the path, the shell will continue to use the version it found originally (until, e.g., you reset the PATH variable). `command -v` knows which version the shell is using. `which ` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

I use `which` quite often to quickly dive into executable like this: `vim $(which my_executable)`. Recently I found this post and was quite surprised -- I have been doing this wrong all the time? But then I checked all the answers and didn't find any reason to drop `which` entirely. Moreover, no one answer provided me with drop-in replacement for `vim $(which my_executable)`: (output is left as is)

```
$ type -a pacman
pacman is aliased to `pacman'
pacman is /usr/bin/pacman
$ command -v pacman
alias pacman='pacman'
$ which pacman
/usr/bin/pacman
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

> The which command is a broken heritage from the C-Shell and is better
> left alone in Bourne-like shells.

I think that you should use any tool as long as it covers all your needs. I use `which` to find executable path in `$PATH`, and of course it is not apropriate tool to investigate what actually stands behind your command and then `type` and `command` would fit better.

Comment: The problem is that `vim $(which command)` could make you open a file that is completely irrelevant and not actually what is executed when you run `command`.

Comment: It's a bit clunky, but `with_path() { "${@:1:$#-1}" "$( unset -f "${@:$#}" ; unalias "${@:$#}" 2>/dev/null ; command -v "${@:$#}" )" ; } ; with_path vim pacman` should edit the actual `pacman` executable script, ignoring any aliases and functions.

Comment: At minimum, `vim "$( which someprog )"` with the double quotes will prevent (most) weirdness with wildcard and whitespace in the resulting filename.

Answer (score 3):

(Since this question is tagged with "portability", various interpretations of the question are excluded, including "interactive use" and "I only care about the system I'm using". So this answer only considers *Why shouldn't I do this in a shell script?*)

Stéphane has presented a comprehensive analysis of the options, with reasons why each are good or bad. There's no one reason why `which` is always the wrong answer. Rather there are a multitude of smaller contributing factors. While you might be tolerant of one or a few of them, taken together they might change your mind.

One reason not yet mentioned for not using `which` is that it begs the question:

### Why do you want the output of `which` in the first place?

By which I mean, sometimes the goal shouldn't be to find a drop-in replacement for `which`, but rather to refactor the code in a way that doesn't need it in the first place.

A common pattern is:

```bash
CMD=$( which cmd )

# some time later...
$CMD --some --args
```

Leaving aside the fact that `$CMD` is almost always unquoted, I would argue that this entire pattern is broken.

It's one thing to hard-code `CMD=/my/path/to/cmd` when the point is to avoid depending on `$PATH`.

But if you're going to search in `$PATH` anyway, then there's almost always no point. Get rid of `which` and `$CMD` entirely, and just write:

```bash
cmd --some --args
```

If you think you need the path because you want to embed it in a function or alias, then that's where `command` comes in:

```bash
function cmd {
    command cmd --extra-arg "$@"
}
```

There are of course exceptions where you need a program based on a different `PATH`. In that case consider using:

```bash
function cmd {
    PATH=$OTHERPATH command cmd "$@"
}
```

The point, overall, is to *avoid* having a mental shortcut for "how do I get the path to a command", and instead consider on a case-by-case basis: *do I really need the path and why?*

In some cases `which` may be acceptable, but at least some of the time there will be better solutions. If you're writing a tutorial for other people, please try harder to think of other options.

---

Even if you think that `CMD=$( which cmd ) ; ... $CMD args` is warranted, there are other reasons to avoid `which`

### It's not universal

The [list of commands required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) includes `command` and `type` but not `which`.

### Its output format is unspecified

`which` is only obliged to *indicate* the path to the named command, not to provide it verbatim and free of commentary. Although most versions.

It's perfectly legal for `which foo` to output something like:

- `foo might be /opt/foobar/bin/foo (unverified)`; or
- `foo is in /bin`; or
- `~foo/bin/foo` (where `~foo` denote's foo's home dir); or
- `/proc/1234/root/bin/foo` (where process 1234 has since terminated)

### the answer can get out of date

(This basically excludes all forms of `CMD=$( something ) ; ... $CMD ...` and is not specific to `which`.)

For various reasons, the location of the executable for a given command name can change.

Sometimes you want the old location, and sometimes you don't.

Occasionally the path to a command is relative (starting at `.` rather than `/`). This is rare because it's generally frowned upon as a security risk, but might still apply in special cases, in which case simply going `cd` can invalidated the path to a program.

Comment: Do you feel that `whereis` is any "better" than `which`?

Comment: @Seamus that depends; how and why are you using `which`? Is your use-case covered by any of the scenarios that I've mentioned above?

Comment: @Seamus I reiterate this point: before one asks "how do I get the path to a command", it is more appropriate to step back, and ask yourself _why_ do I need the path _in this case_, and is there a simpler design that means I don't need to know the path at all?